# Access network in main thread in OS: for Review is OK?

Tags: ios, iphone, networking, appstore-approval

In my iPhone App, login function is accessing internet in the main thread.
Is it ok to access internet in the main thread?
Some other processes are also accessing internet in main thread in different screen.

Will it be rejected in review process?

Please guide me.

Thanks.
--Ruhul

Comment: No one can tell you what Apple will accept or not. But in general, it is bad practice to do any network access on the main thread.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns the policies and procedures of app distribution services, rather than programming. Please refer to: [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?‍](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165), [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?(https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Answer (score 0):

As a rule, network access should never be done on the main thread since it blocks the UI and make the app appear unresponsive, because all the UI operations are carried out on the main thread exclusively. There is no specific Apple guideline on not allowing apps which access the network on the main thread, but it may be rejected for the reason of having poor usability due to the UI interaction being blocked for the duration of the network call.